Can a systemd .network configuration file have multiple [Match] sections?
Is the following .network file a valid Systemd network configuration file?  (Notably, the file has three [Match] sections.)
[Match]
Name=enp*

[Match]
Name=ens*

[Match]
Name=enx*

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

The file seems to work as expected.  (Specifically, the single [Network] section seems to be applied to any interface that matches any one of the three [Match] sections).
However, while it seems to work, using multiple [Match] sections does not appear to be documented in the systemd.network(5) man page.
